# HttpsURLConnection strange characters

Tags: java, groovy

all.

I'm trying to connect with a service to get a token by HttpsURLConnection(using groovy). The connection works ok, I'm getting an http code 200, but I'm getting the response with all strage characters.

responseCode: 200
Response Code : 200
Response Msg : OK
********** LINE: ‹       -Ì±
********** LINE: „0Ð^ðdë(‰&±¼   ›uD0’¤Pÿ]‰¶3óæ_WMHÄ)¹^a„NÊnÒDÂÒE…×ÞûóÊªÞ!Â§ÈB>6¾Ý—1r|Þ·9rróý(‡¶}ÒD¡LCðPWçB9ÿý
Response: ‹       -Ì±„0Ð^ðdë(‰&±¼   ›uD0’¤Pÿ]‰¶3óæ_WMHÄ)¹^a„NÊnÒDÂÒE…×ÞûóÊªÞ!Â§ÈB>6¾Ý—1r|Þ·9rróý(‡¶}ÒD¡LCðPWçB9ÿý

The charset i'm using is UTF-8. I've tried by postman and it works ok. I don't know what i'm doin wrong in my code.

```
connection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
outputStreamWriter.write(Parameters);
outputStreamWriter.flush();

int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
String responseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

logger.debug("responseCode: " + responseCode);

if(responseCode == 200){
    logger.debug("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    logger.debug("Response Msg : " + responseMessage);

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null) { //In this while i'm getting the response from service
        response.append(inputLine);
        logger.debug("\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\* LINE: " + inputLine);
    }
    input.close();

    logger.debug("Response: " + response.toString()); //Here  i'm printing the response in the log file
    
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
    token = jsonObj.getString("access_token");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not binary stream, but text this certainly seems like an encoding issue.

By using `new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())` you will use the default charset - does that match what is in the stream?

Try looking at what the URLConnection is reporting as the encoding/content type : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html

Then look how a library handles the conversion, for instance:
Apache's HttpClient [BasicHttpClientResponseHandler](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/master/httpclient5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/classic/BasicHttpClientResponseHandler.java) delegates to `EntityUtils`, have a look at how that works: [EntityUtils.java](http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=httpcore/httpcore/src/main/java/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.java)

But overall, why not save yourself the pain and use a library to do this? Several are discussed here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-http-response-body-as-string